# Div appears twice in I.E. for no reason at all. In other browsers it works fine

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The page contains a loginform which is held by the div "login". In IE9 that div is displayed twice.

I studied the CSS and HTML and source in several browsers. I can't find any reason for IE to display the div twice.

The site can be found here: http://atbfacturen.wietze.uwvakman.nl:81/

It's unclear to me why IE does this.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="/users/home"><img src="/img/atblogo_black.png" alt="Logo ATB Facturen" /></a>            

        <div id="headerOptions">
            Tuesday 06 September 2011&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/pages/help">Hulp</a>            
        </div>
    </div>


    <form action="/" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
        </div>
    <div id="login">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Gebruikersnaam</strong></td>

            <td><input name="data[User][username]" type="text" style="width:150px" maxlength="50" id="UserUsername" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Wachtwoord</strong></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="data[User][password]" style="width:150px" id="UserPassword" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Aanmelden" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#login {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without nesting the TABLE inside the DIV?

Comment: Step 1) Correct your markup. Your nesting is broken. Step 2) Debug again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are closing your div inscie of a `<tr>` element when the `<div>` element was opened outside of the `<table>` as a whole.

IE is probably trying to clean up your markup a bit for you due to what it considers illegal nesting of tags

Comment: It was the submit div which was closed in the <tr>. I fixed it, but it didn't help.

Comment: its not just that one, your whole DOM is a mess.  You are closing your `<form/>` element inside of the table rows as well.  There are numerous DOM markup issues that are most definitely the cause of your problems

Comment: It was CakePHP $form->end() which put the </form> in the <td></td>. I fixed this and the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you would take time and indent your HTML properly, you'd see your misaligned tags immediately. Also, running your website through [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fatbfacturen.wietze.uwvakman.nl%3A81%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) tends to help in these cases.

In fact, I'd advise to always run your webpages through the validator. I can hurt your feelings, but more often than not it will show you many small things that you missed. You don't have to fix all of them (sometimes there are good reasons for things to be the way they are), but it never hurts to fix as many as possible.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="/users/home"><img src="/img/atblogo_black.png" alt="Logo ATB Facturen" /></a>
        <div id="headerOptions">
            Tuesday 06 September 2011&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/pages/help">Hulp</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="/" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
        </div>
        <div id="login">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Gebruikersnaam</strong></td>
                    <td><input name="data[User][username]" type="text" style="width:150px" maxlength="50" id="UserUsername" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Wachtwoord</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="data[User][password]" style="width:150px" id="UserPassword" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="submit">
                            <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden" />
                        </div>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I used the HTML validator using the Firefox webtoolbar. There are several issues, but I didn't knew whether it would fix the issue. Also since I'm using CakePHP framework there are several issues I can't fix at this moment. I pasted the HTML from source in FF. In my own file I've indented the code.

Comment: +1 - don't hesitate, validate! When you're working with a framework that introduces its own validation errors, it's useful to pull out your code and paste it into a clean HTML template, then validate that.

Comment: Vilx, is your code snippet supposed to be a fixed version? You've still got the form and the table closing tags mixed up...

Comment: No, it's supposed to emphasize the problem.